# Create kubeconfig with restricted permission

Tags: azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I need to create a kubeconfig with restricted access, I want to be able to provide permission to update configmap in specific namesapce, how can I create such a kubeconfig with the following permission

> 1. for specefic namespace (myns)
> 2. update only configmap (mycm)

Is there a simple way to create it ?

The **tricky part** here is that I need that some program will have access to cluster X and modify only this comfigMap, How would I do it from outside process without providing the full kubeconfig file which can be problematic from security reason

To make it clear, I own the cluster, I just want to give to some program restricted permissions

Comment: Do you have access to the cluster and permission to create objects at myns namespace?

Comment: @hariK - I've permission to the cluster. I've create it. what I want to provide to some program restricted permission, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not straight forward. But still possible.

Create the namespace myns if not exists.

```
$ kubectl create ns myns
namespace/myns created
```

Create a service account cm-user in myns namespace. It'll create a secret token as well.

```
$ kubectl create sa cm-user -n myns
serviceaccount/cm-user created

$  kubectl get sa cm-user -n myns
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
cm-user   1         18s

$ kubectl get secrets -n myns
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
cm-user-token-kv5j5   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      63s
default-token-m7j9v   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      96s
```

Get the token and ca.crt from `cm-user-token-kv5j5` secret.

```
$ kubectl get secrets cm-user-token-kv5j5 -n myns -oyaml
```

Base64 decode the value of token from `cm-user-token-kv5j5`.

Now create a user using the decoded token.

```
$ kubectl config set-credentials cm-user --token=<decoded token value>
User "cm-user" set.
```

Now generate a kubeconfig file kubeconfig-cm.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <ca.crt value from cm-user-token-kv5j5 secret>
    server: <kubernetes server>
  name: <cluster>
contexts:
- context:
    cluster:<cluster>
    namespace: myns
    user: cm-user
  name: cm-user
current-context: cm-user 
users:
- name: cm-user
  user:
    token: <decoded token>
```

Now create a role and rolebinding for sa cm-user.

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: myns
  name: cm-user-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  verbs: ["update", "get", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cm-user-rb
  namespace: myns
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: cm-user-role
subjects:
- namespace: myns
  kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cm-user
```

We are done. Now using this kubeconfig file you can update the mycm configmap. It doesn't have any other privileges.

```
$ kubectl get cm -n myns --kubeconfig kubeconfig-cm
NAME                 DATA   AGE
mycm                 0      8s

$ kubectl delete cm mycm -n myns --kubeconfig kubeconfig-cm
Error from server (Forbidden): configmaps "mycm" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:myns:cm-user" cannot delete resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "myns"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RBAC and define `role` and then bind that role to a `user` or `serviceaccount` using `rolebinding`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: configmap-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  verbs: ["update", "get", "list"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This role binding allows "jane" to read config maps in the "default" namespace.
# You need to already have a Role named "configmap-reader" in that namespace.
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-configmap
  namespace: default
subjects:
# You can specify more than one "subject"
- kind: User
  name: jane # "name" is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  # "roleRef" specifies the binding to a Role / ClusterRole
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: configmap-reader # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: Thanks, but how should I create a kubeconfig from it ?

Comment: Kubeconfig is for authentication. It will not have authorization policies.

Comment: it's a bit more complicated ...I need to run a program that that connect to cluster and modify some `configmap`, the program should store the `kubeconfig` to connect to the cluster, I dont want to store the kubeconfig in that progam from security reason, I want to store some very lighet kubeconig with the ability to modify only this configmap

Comment: that program is running in kubernetes cluster or outside it?

Comment: Its' runnig from outside and should connect to k8s cluster and modify specific config map

Comment: The policies that I have given in the answer will not be in kubeconfig..it will be in the kubernetes cluster